# Discord JS v12 Function Problem (My function is not getting recognized properly)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I have a problem importing/writing a function which calculates Currency A into Currency B. The problem is that the function is not recognized properly.
My Function:

```
async function convertRMB(inputAmount) {
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    try {
        const responseRMB = await fetch('http://www.floatrates.com/daily/cny.json');
        const dataRMB = responseRMB.json();

        const rateEUR = dataRMB.eur.rate
        const rateUSD = dataRMB.usd.rate

        const RMBinEUR = Number(inputAmount) * Number(rateEUR)
        const RMBinUSD = Number(inputAmount) * Number(rateUSD)


        return RMBinEUR;
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}


module.exports = {convertRMB};
```

The Class im using the function in:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const convertRMB = require('../functions/convertRMB');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    var inputAmount = args.join(' ');

    const amountEUR = convertRMB(inputAmount);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`${inputAmount}RMB = ${amountEUR}€`)
        .setFooter("© CSGO Library")
    message.channel.send(embed);

    convertRMB(inputAmount);

};

module.exports.help = {
    name: `rmb`
}
```

The Error im getting:
"TypeError: convertRMB is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, "convertRMB" is not a function: it is the export object of your file `convertRMB.js`. You exported the function `convertRMB()` as a function of `module.export`, or to be clearer, is the same thing as:

```js
module.export.convertRMB = function (input) {...};
```

To obtain what you want, that is to export the function as an anonymous one, you should do something like this:

```js
module.exports = function (input) {...};
```

Or, using your code, you can use the export object that you have:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    var inputAmount = args.join(' ');

    const amountEUR = convertRMB.convertRMB(inputAmount);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`${inputAmount}RMB = ${amountEUR}€`)
        .setFooter("© CSGO Library")
    message.channel.send(embed);

    convertRMB.convertRMB(inputAmount);

};
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports) you can find some useful example to better understand the `module.export` dynamics.